# how to customize UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i want to customize table cell to show data like this (chk image)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those rows which you want set color like above the simply set this color (shown in above pic) fo cell' background color.

or find this color use digital meter and use that rgb. like this

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255 green:200.0/255 blue:200.0/255 alpha:1.0];
```

replace 200.0 with your rgb values

waht you need, you need to store data in common array for simply showing single detail you need to save that in form of string others in dictionary format.
And at time of showing data.

check wheter object is string or dictionary, and show accordingly.

for checking type of object use this

```
if([[myArray objectAtIndex:index] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
```

Comment: i think there is only one row in every section and i have to show both heading and fixture data in that single row. am i right ??

Comment: yep you right.if this is dynamic and you fetch it from somwhere then after fetchin data you can make an string for your first row with yellow background.then make an array with your data. and make all other adjustments. set hight for row o in each section is less than others. and you can set it's backgroundColor.Means you have a big assignment for now. not very typical task but need a portion of your mind.

Comment: are you trying to say that i have to use 2 rows in every cell row 0 for header and row 1 for data?

Comment: i have suggeted this option but you can do it in other ways also. But this concept is also not bad.

Comment: well i have implemented your suggestion and now i have 1 colorful header. Now for row 1 i cant set its height bcuz data is dynamic, so what i am thinking is to insert a UITextView as cell's contentView.

Comment: For dynamic text find the height by calculating text size and add some extra for adjustments. see sizeWithFont: method of NSString

Comment: ok i will check it now, but suppose i am setting the its height correctly, now is this possible to show data in that kind of format?? Like space between 2 teams and multiple line data. is this possible??

Comment: Yes it is possible, manage while making label in your table cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass UITableViewCell.

In Xcode -> New File -> Objective-C class -> Subclass of UITableViewCell

Then in your tableview at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   MySubclassedTableviewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MySubclassedTableviewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement delegate method of viewForHeaderInSection: and implement view for yellow area shown in screenshot, and for for rest, you can implement custom table view cell inherited from UITableViewCell

Comment: that yellow area is our section header?? are you sure ??

Answer (score 0):

[Use custom tableviewcell](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder)